# Add new line to a text file in loop statement

Tags: c#, loops, text-files, newline

I created a loop that takes user names from a text boxes. I would like to put the names into a text file and add a new line each time. It's not working. It's once again overrides the previous name. I know how to add new line to a text file, but in the loop statement it dose not work.
Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txt_user.length ; i++ )
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\mail\users.txt", txt_user[i].Text + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Here is a sample code out of the loop as writing a new line - and it works:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\mail\users.txt", txt_user1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "abc");
```

Comment: Well `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the contents. You want to open the file and write lines to it. I'd recommend you look at `StreamWriter`. Also note the way you have it now (assuming it worked) would open the file, write a line, close the file, repeat, repeat, repeat. That's bad. You want to open it, write all your stuff, then close it. Much more efficient.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx Has all info you need

Comment: Use the `AppendAllText` method instead.

Comment: I would recommend against @Jens solution for the reason I mentioned. There is no reason to keep opening and closing the file over and over. That's much more inefficient than doing it once.

Comment: @dman2306 Not necessarily. He could build the whole string in a stringbuilder and write it all at once. Also, "too inefficient" is determined by the amount of lines.

Comment: @Jens Agreed, but you didn't mention a `StringBuilder` until now. You just told him to use a different method.

Comment: @dman2306 Which works but is not a complete answer, hence posted as a comment. I in fact agree with you, a simple streamwriter is the best course of action imho. :-)

Comment: Thank you all - i use AppendAllText and its work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close: there is [File.AppendAllText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [File.AppendText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You could also collect all lines in memory first and use [File.AppendAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd383691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you have enough RAM to store all lines).

`WriteAllText()` will write a new file or overwrite an existing one.

This will work well enough for smaller files, since the OS may apply some caching strategies. However, doing that in a loop for very large files may not be efficient. You should have a look at [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s then.

Comment: Considering we have no idea if his loop has 2 entries or 2 billion I think this is bad advice. He should File.Open outside the loop, write his contents, then close the stream outside the loop. This answer could potentially open/close the file billions of times since we have no idea how many times the loop executes.

Comment: @ThomasWeller None of these are as efficient as the answer I gave, and I would hardly consider my answer difficult to implement.  Why do it the wrong way when the right way is so easy?  Although, I do agree, it would be silly to assume he has billions of text controls.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Why make assumptions when you do not know his requirements? When programmers build what they "think" the user wants not what the user wants, that's how we get design flaws.

Comment: @dman2306: alright. Feel free to add a better answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @dman: Also consider that OP is still learning. He learned once piece now. Just enough he'll understand. The StreamWriter solution involves a `using` statement. What if he wants to add text later? The `using` will be in his way, he removes it and runs into IDisposable issues. That's not better. If you suggest a `using` statement, don't forget to tell him what it means.

Comment: @dman2306 Considering that he said that he is taking the user names from Textboxes, and you can only have roughly 2500 textboxes on a winform before you run out of window handles, it is safe to assume he has less than 2500.  (Processes can only have 10,000 window handles in total, and I'm guessing each textbox takes 4).

Comment: @RobertMcKee I thought we were discussing software design, not arguing semantics. Would you not agree that opening and closing the file even 2 times is 1 time more than necessary?

Comment: @dman2306 Yes, I wouldn't open and close the file multiple times.  I have  too many other processes that I've written in the past that trigger on file changes that this code would be horrendous.  Virus scan or backup file on file changes? This code just triggered 1,000 virus scans and backups.  Yuck.  Ok, I actually do usually debounce file change events to prevent such scenarios, but maybe not all do...  It could really be bad on SSDs as well (if no caching is used).

Answer (score 2):

If you have too many entities it's better use this code

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\mail\users.txt")) 
        {
      for (int i = 0; i < txt_user.length ; i++ )
           {
            sw.WriteLine(txt_user[i].Text);   
           }
        }
```

Comment: Except won't the extra WriteLine end up making it end \r\n\r\n\r\n between each record? WriteLine already ends it with a new line.

Answer (score 2):

This will open the file once, and write lines to the text file as it enumerates them, and then close the file.  It doesn't do multiple opens, nor does it try and build up a large string in the process, which likely makes it the most I/O and memory efficient of the bunch of answers given so far.

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\mail\users.txt",
  Enumerable
    .Range(0,txt_user.length)
    .Select(i=>txt_user[i].Text));
```

Comment: Even I dislike LINQ, your answer may be as efficient as the StreamWriter solution: +1

Comment: WriteAllLines is essentially the streamwriter solution under the covers without reinventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use File.AppendText if you want to add to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use a StringBuilder:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < txt_user.length ; i++ )
    builder.AppendLine(txt_user[i].Text);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\mail\users.txt", builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of openeing and closing the file all the time (because this what `File.WriteAllText` does at every call), prepare the text by using a string builder and write it to the file at once. Since the text comes from text boxes, I assume that the resulting string will not be very long anyway.

```
var sb = new Stringbuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < txt_user.length; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(txt_user[i].Text);
}
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\mail\users.txt", sb.ToString());
```